# How to select date columns from every table in the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to select the minimum date from every date column inside my database. What I mean with minimum is that I want to obtain the earliest date.

From what I've been investigating, it seems that the best approach is to use dynamic SQL. This is the code I'm currently trying but I can't get anything out of it.

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) 

SELECT @Sql = STUFF(
        (       
            SELECT ' UNION ALL SELECT '''+ MIN(C.COLUMN_NAME) +','+''''+ C.TABLE_NAME +''' As TableName FROM '+ C.TABLE_SCHEMA+ '.' +C.TABLE_NAME
            FROM Information_schema.Columns C
            JOIN Information_schema.Tables T
            ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
            WHERE C.DATA_TYPE in ('datetime','date','datetime2','timestamp','time')
                and C.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('STG','HIST')
                and C.TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('COSTOS')
                and T.TABLE_TYPE <> 'VIEW'
            GROUP BY C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 11, '')

EXEC(@Sql)
SELECT @Sql
```

I'm not familiar with dynamic SQL and the output of this query is a null result.

Comment: I would work on creating a few dynamic queries from the system tables and just selecting/printing them out (instead of executing them).  Then view the code and see if the queries are built correctly and you get the results before trying to do it on all the tables at once.

Also if you have too many dates the query could end up being HUGE.  You may want to convert it to a LOOP and do one table or column at a time insert into a temp/stage table.  Then select from that temp table to get the full results instead of doing it all in one query (plus perfromance coudl be bad as well)

Comment: The poorly named `timestamp` data type is the same as `ROWVERSION` and has nothing to do with date or time. You are missing `datatimeoffset`.

Comment: Print your SQL and debug it. Also don't use information_schema use the proper `sys`tem views. What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using Version 1.5. 
What's wrong with using information_schema?

Also yes, I noticed that this query could perform badly but since it's a one time thing  I wanted to get the result first. I'll try to improve it anyways for possible future uses

Comment: No, you're not, what does `@@version` return? And see [what-can-go-wrong-while-querying-information-schema-for-schema-names](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294550/what-can-go-wrong-while-querying-information-schema-for-schema-names)

Comment: Sorry, I meant 15.0. Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)

Comment: In which case there is no need to use the slow legacy `for xml` hack, use `string_agg()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on your attempt, one thing you need to do is to put `MIN()` inside the statement:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @err int

SELECT @sql = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT 
        'UNION ALL SELECT ' +
        QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME, '''') + ' AS [TableName], ' +
        QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA, '''') + ' AS [SchemaName], ' +
        QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME, '''') + ' AS [ColumnName], ' +
        'MIN(' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ') AS [ColumnValue] '  +
        'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME) + ' '
    FROM Information_schema.Columns C
    JOIN Information_schema.Tables T ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE 
        C.DATA_TYPE IN ('datetime','date','datetime2','timestamp','time')
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('STG','HIST')
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('COSTOS')
        AND T.TABLE_TYPE <> 'VIEW'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 10, '')

PRINT @sql
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: @Charlieface, thanks, escaping is important.